# Converting a PDF to JPG with ImageMagick in PHP Gives Odd Letter Spacing

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, exec, jpeg

I am trying to convert a PDF to a JPG with a PHP `exec()` call, which looks like this:

```
convert page.pdf -resize 716x716 page.jpg
```

For some reason, the JPG comes out with janky text, despite the PDF looking just fine in Acrobat and Mac Preview. Here is the original PDF:

http://whit.info/dev/conversion/page.pdf

and here is the janktastic output:

http://whit.info/dev/conversion/page.jpg

The server is a LAMP stack with PHP 5 and ImageMagick 6.2.8.

Can you help this stumped Geek?

Thanks in advance,

Whit

Comment: What version of GS is imagemagick using?

Comment: How do you locate the GS version? I can find ImageMagick in the phpinfo file, but not GS.

Comment: imageMagick uses GS to render PDFs.  PHP never touches it directly once IM is configured.  If you're running windows, you'll find it in you program files folder.  You should have a "gs" folder.  In that will be a "gs#.##" folder.  Those #'s are the version number.  If it's already in your path, you can just type "gswin32c" at the command line (or gs for you unixy folks).

Comment: I am running it on a LAMP stack at Rackspace.

Comment: Then you'll probably be able to get the version by running `gs -v` on a command line. (I see the same issue with gs 8.71).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick is just going to call out to Ghostscript to convert this PDF to an image. If you run `gs` on the pdf, you get the same badly-spaced output.

I suspect Ghostscript isn't handling the PDF's embedded TrueType fonts very well. If you could change your output to either embed Type 1 fonts or use a "core" PostScript font, you'd get better results.

Comment: Unfortunately these are the fonts from the designer. They are Adobe fonts, and show up well everywhere but these converted images.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect its an encoding/widths issue.  Both are a tad off, though I can't put my finger on why.

Here are some suspects:

**First**

The text stream is defined in UTF-16 LE.  charNULLcharNULL, using the normal string drawing command syntax:

`(some text) Tj`

There's a way to escape any old character value into a () string.  You can also define strings in hex thusly:

`<203245> Tj`

Neither method are used, just the questionable inline nulls.  That could cause an issue in GS if it's trying to work with pointers to char without lengths associated with them.

**Second**

The widths array is dumb.  You can define widths in groups thusly:

`[ 32 [450 525 500] 37 [600 250] 40 [0] ]`

This defines
32: 450
33: 525
34: 500
37: 600
38: 250
40: 0

These fonts defines their consecutive widths in individual arrays.  Not illegal, but definitely wasteful/stupid, and if GS were coded to EXPECT gaps between the arrays, it could induce a bug.

There's also some extremely fishy values in the array.  32 through 126 are defined consecutively, but then it starts jumping all over: `...126 [600] 8364 [500] 8216 [222] 402 [500] 8222 [389]. 8230 [1000] 8224 [444]..`. and then goes back to being consecutive from 160 to 255.

Just weird.

**Third**

I'm not even remotely sure, but the CIDToGIDMap stream contains an AWEFUL lot of nulls.

**Bottom line**

Those fonts are fishy.  And I've never heard of "Bellflower Books" or "UFPDF 0.1"

That version number makes me cringe.  It should make you cringe too.

Googleing for "UFPDF" I found this note from the author:

> Note: I wrote UFPDF as an experiment, not as a finished product. If you have problems using it, don't bug me for support. Patches are welcome though, but I don't have much time to maintain this.

UFPDF is a PHP library that sits on top of FPDF.  0.1.  Just run away.