# PHP Imagick PDF to JPEG Character Spacing Issue

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, jpeg, imagick

I'm using php imagick to convert a generated invoice to JPEG.

However the letter spacings are all off.

You can see that both Before & After files have considerably different text and letter spacing.

**Before** (PDF File):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uMQb6gSWmZFX6phBrR4_arE9h-__qX0V

..AND **AFTER**

[image: After]

```html
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagick->readImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/sign2/'.$invoice_path);
    $noofpages = (int)$imagick->getNumberImages();
    $x = 0;

    $page = new Imagick();
    $page->setResolution(300,300);
    while($x < $noofpages){
        $page->readImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/sign2/'.$invoice_path.'['.$x.']');
        $page->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
        $page->setImageFormat('jpg');
        $page->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
        $page->setImageCompressionQuality(60);
        $page->writeImage($user_folder.'/tmp/page_'.$x.'.jpg');
        $x++;
    }
```

Its definitely not a pdf issue as i can convert this pdf perfectly to jpeg on other websites that provide such conversions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a font issue? The other font looks okay. See [Odd Letter Spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268990/924299) and [text overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54045015/924299).

Comment: but how do i settle the fonts?

Comment: can i do it on imagick?

Comment: I don' think its an issue with the file. As i can completely convert this perfectly with other pdf to jpeg converters online.

Comment: Imagick uses Ghostscript to do the conversion. That's a command line tool you can invoke yourself. I'd recommend testing that from the command line to isolate where the error is, and maybe try newer versions of Ghostscript.

But as Showdev said, this is likely to be a missing font on your system.